# mix-blend-mode broken when html has "perspective"

Tags: css, css-transforms, blending

By applying **"perspective"** to the *html* element my **mix-blend-mode** seems to get ignored by Firefox.

```
html {
    perspective: 800px; /* causing the issue */
}

div {
    color: #fff;    
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, orange);
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

What is the issue with that?
I am using Firefox 40.

http://codepen.io/Type-Style/pen/oXJbRE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can achieve your expected result by simply adding a mix-blend-mode to the html element.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2bmgs5nc/1/)**

```css
html {
  background-color: #111;
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/W3C%C2%AE_Icon.svg/210px-W3C%C2%AE_Icon.svg.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  perspective: 800px;
  mix-blend-mode: screen; /*see change here*/
}
div {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, orange);
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some more Text</div>
```

I'm not entirely sure what was causing the issue, but both perspective and mix-blend-mode will create a new stacking context so it may have something to do with that...

Comment: Stackingcontext might be an issue. I fliped out perspective with opacity: 0.99and got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that, when defining the `perspective` property for an element, it is the **CHILD** elements that get the perspective view, **NOT** the element itself, you **still** have to call on your child element, and assign your desired **CSS** perspective properties to it, in order to have it running cross-browser. The codes below are working 100% an any existing browser;

```
html {
    background-color: #111;
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/W3C%C2%AE_Icon.svg/210px-W3C%C2%AE_Icon.svg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
} 

div {
    height: 100px; line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;    
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, orange);
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

.background-image{
    perspective: 50px; // calling on child element and applying the perspective
}
```

**What was the issue?**

Defining your **perspective** properties under the **`HTML`** tag causes issues for cross-browsers compatibility, as you may have numerous elements under your main `html` tag, and the browser may not distinguish how and which element to apply it to. It is true that the perspective property only affects 3D transformed elements, but it's not a guaranty that any browsers detects and applies it to the image specified as a main background. 
I hope it helped.